# Constructor to initialize base part of derived class by object of another derived class

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Let's say I have a base class and 2 derived classes:

```
class Base {
   public:
      Base() : m_base(0) { }
   private:
      int m_base; 
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
   public:
      Derived1() : Base(), m_d1(1) { }
   private:
      int m_d1;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
   public:
      Derived2(): Base(), m_d2(2.5) { }
   private:
      double m_d2;
};
```

I now want an overloaded constructor to construct an instance of `Derived2` by initializing its base part by an instance of `Derived1` where I came across some different approaches:

1. Pointer to `Derived1` + `dynamic_cast` + base class copy-constructor within initializer list:

   `Derived2(Derived1 *d1) : Base(*(dynamic_cast<Base*>(d1))), m_d2(3.5) { }`

   Obviously this has the problem of de-referencing an invalid pointer
2. Reference to `Base` and cast `Derived1` when calling:

   ```
   Derived2(const Base &base) : Base(base), m_d2(3.5) { }
   // ...
   Derived1 d1 = Derived1();
   Derived2 d2 = Derived2(static_cast<Base>(d1));
   ```
3. Call default constructor of `Base` first and then initialize every single member:

   ```
   Derived2(Derived *d1) : Base(), m_d2(3.5) {
      if (d1) {
          m_base = d1->base();
      }
    }
   ```

   But this needs access to the members of `Derived1` as well as the members of `Base` to be `protected`

Most certainly there is another better way - So which is the best way to achieve this and why?

Comment: If you remember that inheritance is an "is-a" relationship, then you can see that `Derived1` "is-a" `Base`. Which means that `d1` is also of the type `Base` already. So you don't need the cast in the second option. So that's what I recommend you go for. And in the first case, you could use a pointer to `Base` as the argument instead, then you don't need the cast there either.

Comment: `Obviously this has the problem of de-referencing an invalid pointer` What invalid pointer?

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude Good hint, I was stuck in the thought that I should always use `dynamic_cast` to get base part of a derived class

Comment: @tkausl The constructor could be called with `NULL` as argument e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Pointer to Derived1 + dynamic_cast + base class copy-constructor within initializer list

There is no need for pointers, no need for dynamic casting, and no need to limit the argument to only `Derived1`.

> 2. Reference to Base and cast Derived1 when calling

This is fine, except the cast is redundant. An object is implicitly convertible to its base.

> 3. Call default constructor of Base first and then initialize every single member

This is pointlessly complicated, and will not be an option in cases where base is not default initialisable.

---

Another alternative is to pass the base by value, and move from it:

```
Derived2(Base base) : Base(std::move(base))
```

This allows avoiding a copy from rvalue arguments. That won't be particularly useful for the trivial `Base` in the example, but can be much faster for some real example that is slow to copy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast to a base type.

The most direct translation of what you say you want to do is

```
Derived2(const Derived1& d1): Base(d1), m_d2(2.5) { }
```

and then all you need is

```
Derived1 d1;
Derived2 d2(d1);
```

If you want to accept any type derived from `Base`:

```
Derived2(const Base& b): Base(b), m_d2(2.5) { }
```